# jQuery submit doesn't handle "success"

Tags: javascript, jquery, webforms, clojure

I've gone through all of the solutions I could find on Stack Overflow and Google but none of them seem to help.

I have a function in Clojure (Noir framework) that takes two keys, "text" and "day-of-note" and inserts the values into a database. Regardless of whether or not that works, the function returns a JSON response with {"result":true} (for testing purposes).

```
(defpage [:post "/newpost"] {:keys [text day-of-note]}
  []
  (println "newpost called")
  (post text)
  (response/json {:result true}))
```

My form is a simple form with one textarea, a checkbox and a button.

```
<form action="/newpost" id="new-post" method="post">
  <textarea id="entry" name="text">Insert todays happenings</textarea>
    <br />
  <input checked="checked" name="day-of-note" type="checkbox" value="true">
  <input type="submit" value="Add entry">
</form>
```

When submitting the form I have added a call to alert to show me the contents of dataString and they are formatted correctly ("text=lalala&day-of-note=true").

```
$(function () {
  $("#new-post").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var dataString = $("#new-post").serialize();
    alert(dataString);
    $.ajax({
      url: "/newpost",
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      data: dataString,
      success: function () {
          alert("Success!");
      };
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

What happens here when the code is as it is above, there is a HTML call to /newpost when the user click on the button and the page shows {"result":true}. If I comment out the "$.ajax"-part the message box pops up with the correct content, but if I remove the comments -- no message box, just goes straight to /newpost.

What I thought was supposed to happen was that the /newpost page would never be rendered but a call with the dataString would be put to it by Ajax and a message box with "Success!" would be shown.

Where am I taking the wrong turn?

Comment: You have an extra semi-colon after `success: function(){}`. Try removing it and see if it works better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the semi-colon after the `success` function declaration:

```
success: function () {
    alert("Success!");
}
```

The `success` function declaration is part of an object, which separates declarations by comma.